# SP 2013 Content Type Hub Issue after restoring in staging environment

Tags: backup, restore, content-type-hub

We have a SP 2013 farm where content type hub is configured and publishing works fine in my Development Environment and we have a content type called BasicCT is been created with 4 site columns.We ran the timer jobs and it was available in the subscriber site collections.

Now we have taken the backup and restore of this site collection and moved into staging environment.Everything works fine till now.Today we have a new requirement and we  were told to  create a site column called "`mywfstatus`" in CTH and told to push to the site collections. We have created this on Dev.Env and tested our functionality and verified everything working correctly. Now we need to  move this to staging environment.I have created "`mywfstatus`" the  site column in staging's CTH site collection and ran the timer job.Surprisingly this newly created site column did not push to the subscriber site collections in my staging.The subscriber site collections that are in staging are the backed/restored site collections from dev.env.I am stuck with why my "`mywfstatus`" column is not available in these subscribers in staging. I have not moved the MMS database from dev.env to staging as my customer already provisioned the MMS and CTH in staging.

Just wanted to know whether this process taking the backup an restore of CTH  DB was not correct or do I supposed to  take the MMS DB also from dev env. to staging? Is it because the newly created  site columns in CTH will be pushed to subscribers only if the site collections were created through UI or powershell?Why its not working when we moved the sites through backup and restore method? If this is a bug  in CTH,then the entire purpose of CTH itself is defeated.